# Synchronizing Two Folders using SFTP

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I have a local folder (on macOS) with some missing files and corrupt data and a folder on a remote server (ubuntu) with uncorrupted data. How can I fix the corrupted/missing files on my local machine without redownloading the entire folder (around 500gb)?

I have tried reget -Pr, get -Pra, in SFTP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `rsync` (https://www.mankier.com/1/rsync). It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination.

for example:

```bash
$ rsync -av host.tld:/storage/worship/ ~/worship/
```

This sync remote and local directory `worship`.

Comment: While I agree that `rsync` is the right answer, if there are corrupt files on one end, the OP will want to use the `-c, --checksum` option(s).  While the sync will take longer with that option, without that option, `rsync` does it's work based upon filesystem timestamps and reported file sizes.  If those two match (or are newer) on the destination, the files will __not__ be copied/replaced.